# What exactly is WPF?

Tags: wpf, windows

I have seen lots of questions recently about WPF...

- What is it?
- What does it stand for?
- How can I begin programming WPF?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

WPF is a new technology that will supersede Windows Forms.
WPF stands for Windows Presentation Foundation
Here are some useful topics on SO:

1. [What WPF books would you recommend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591/what-wpf-books-would-you-recommend)
2. [What real world WPF applications are out there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837/what-real-world-wpf-applications-are-out-there)

From my practice I can say that WPF is a truly amazing technology however it takes some time to get used to because it's totally different from the WinForms.
I would recommend you to take a look at this [demo](http://perseus.franklins.net/dnrtvplayer/player.aspx?ShowNum=0115).

Answer (score 5):

WPF is the next frontier with Windows UIs.

- Built on top of DirectX, it opens up hardware acceleration support for
  your .Net 3.0+ user-interfaces.
- Emphasis on Vector Graphics - UIs scale and render better
- Composable UIs. You could nest animated buttons in combo boxes.. the world's your oyster.
- Is a rewrite with only minimal core components written in unmanaged code VS GDI-User Dll based Winforms approach which is a thin managed layer over largely unmanaged code.
- Declarative approach to UI programming, User Interfaces are largely specified in a XML variant called XAML (eXtensible Application markup language) pronounced Zammel. This opens up WPF to designer folks who can specialized tools to craft UIs that the developers can then code up. No translation losses between wireframes to final product.
- MS 'allegedly' will not provide any future updates to Winforms. Heavily invested in WPF as the way forward
- Oh yeah, before I forget. Works best on Vista :)

You can get either Adam Nathan's WPF Unleashed Book or Chris Sells Programming WPF .. those seem to be the way to go. I just read the first chapter of Adam's (Lead for WPF at MS) book. Hence the WPF praise fountains :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here http://windowsclient.net/ and here [Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663326.aspx)

Basically WPF is created to make windows form easier to design because of the use of XAML, designers can work on the design and programmers on the underlying code

Answer (score 1):

WPF is the Windows Presentation Foundation.  It is Microsoft's newest API for building applications with User Interfaces (UIs), working for both standalone and web-based applications.

Unsurprisingly, there is a very detailed but not all that helpful [Windows Presentation Foundation page at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation).

The [WPF Getting Started Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742119.aspx) at the Microsoft MSDN site is probably a better place to start.

Answer (score 1):

Is the new Windows Gui system. I don't believe its aim is to make development easier per se but more to address fundamental issues with WinForm, such as transparency and scaling, neither of which WinForm can effectively address. Furthermore it seeks to address the "one resolution only" paradigm of WinForm by mapping sizes to real-pixel sizes and making flow layout easier and more fundamental.

It's also based on an XML derivative making it easier to change the UI and forcing a  separation of the UI and the core code (although technically you can still badly hack it together in this manner).

This separation also drives a desire to be able to divide the work into two camps, the designers taking charge of the XAML and layout and the programmers taking care of developing the objects used in the XAML.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Eric Sink's [Twelve days of WPF 3D](http://www.ericsink.com/wpf3d/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Windows Presentation Foundation.  It's basically Microsoft's latest attempt to make development easier, and provide a whole heap of nice functionality out of the box.  I'm not sure where to start, but googling "WPF 101" should throw up a few useful links.

Answer (score 0):

WPF is part of the .net 3.0 stack. Its microsoft's next generation Graphical User Interface system. All the information you need can be found on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) and [msdn's wpf site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663326.aspx)

To Get Started programming I guess check out the [essential downloads on windows client](http://windowsclient.net/edownloads.aspx)