# How to migrate this Winform app to WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, winforms

I resurrected code from 10 years ago to draw cards (uses cards.dll). I'll have another program actually manipulate them. I got it working in WinForm, but would really like to figure out a way to access the graphics in WPF.

It works as I'll paste it, but again as a winform:

**Form1.vb:**

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1
    Private SQ As Card = New Card(Suit.Spade, Face.Queen)
    Private DK As Card = New Card(Suit.Diamond, Face.King)
    Private C10 As Card = New Card(Suit.Club, Face.Ten)
    Private H2 As Card = New Card(Suit.Heart, Face.Two)
    Private SA As Card = New Card(Suit.Spade, Face.Ace)
#Region "Form Events"
    Private Sub Main_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load ' MyBase.Load
        Card.Init()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Main_Closing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Closing
        Card.Deinit()
    End Sub
#End Region
    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
        SQ.PaintGraphicFace(e.Graphics, 10, 10)
        DK.PaintGraphicFace(e.Graphics, 50, 10)
        C10.PaintGraphicFace(e.Graphics, 110, 200)
        C10.PaintGraphicBack(e.Graphics, 30, 300)
        H2.PaintGraphicBack(e.Graphics, 250, 370)
        SA.PaintGraphicFace(e.Graphics, 200, 50)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Just getting this far took a bit of work/digging!

**Now Card.vb:**

```
Public Class Card

#Region "Construcor"
    Public Sub New(ByVal cardSuit As Suit, ByVal cardFace As Face)
        Init()
        FCardSuit = cardSuit
        FCardFace = cardFace
    End Sub
#End Region
#Region "Private class vars"
    Private FCardFace As Face
    Private FCardSuit As Suit
#End Region
#Region "External methods and related fields"
    Private Shared initialized As Boolean = False
    Private Shared width As Integer = 75
    Private Shared height As Integer = 100
    '
    Private Declare Function cdtInit Lib "cards.dll" (ByRef width As Integer, ByRef height As Integer) As Boolean
    Private Declare Function cdtDrawExt Lib "cards.dll" (ByVal hdc As IntPtr, ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer, ByVal dx As Integer, ByVal dy As Integer, ByVal card As Integer, ByVal suit As Integer, ByVal color As Integer) As Boolean
    Private Declare Sub cdtTerm Lib "cards.dll" ()
#End Region
#Region "Properties"
    Public Property CardSuit() As Suit
        Get
            Return FCardSuit
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As Suit)
            FCardSuit = Value
        End Set
    End Property
#End Region
#Region "Open & Close"
    Public Shared Sub Init()
        If (initialized) Then Return
        initialized = True
        cdtInit(width, height)
    End Sub
    Public Shared Sub Deinit()
        If (Not initialized) Then Return
        initialized = False
        cdtTerm()
    End Sub
#End Region
#Region "Painting"
    Public Sub PaintGraphicFace(ByVal g As Graphics, ByVal posX As Integer, ByVal posY As Integer)
        PaintGraphicFace(g, posX, posY, width, height)
    End Sub
    Public Sub PaintGraphicFace(ByVal g As Graphics, ByVal posX As Integer, ByVal posY As Integer, ByVal sizeX As Integer, ByVal sizeY As Integer)
        Dim hdc As IntPtr = g.GetHdc()
        Try
            Dim Card As Integer = CType(Me.FCardFace, Integer) * 4 + CType(Me.FCardSuit, Integer)
            cdtDrawExt(hdc, posX, posY, sizeX, sizeY, Card, 0, 0)
        Finally
            g.ReleaseHdc(hdc)
        End Try
    End Sub
    Public Sub PaintGraphicBack(ByVal g As Graphics, ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer)
        PaintGraphicBack(g, x, y, width, height)
    End Sub
    Public Sub PaintGraphicBack(ByVal g As Graphics, ByVal x As Integer, _
     ByVal y As Integer, ByVal dx As Integer, ByVal dy As Integer)
        Dim hdc As IntPtr = g.GetHdc()
        Try
            cdtDrawExt(hdc, x, y, dx, dy, 59, 1, 0)
        Finally
            g.ReleaseHdc(hdc)
        End Try
    End Sub
#End Region

End Class

Public Enum Suit
    Diamond = 1
    Heart = 2
    Spade = 3
    Club = 4
End Enum

Public Enum Face
    Ace = 0
    Two = 1
    Three = 2
    Four = 3
    Five = 4
    Six = 5
    Seven = 6
    Eight = 7
    Nine = 8
    Ten = 9
    Jack = 10
    Queen = 11
    King = 12
End Enum
```

Tweaked a bit from original sources to make more sense, and to get rid of lots of typos in examples over the years... *weird*...

Anyway, the above is enough to get someone painting cards immediately. I could not find any such working examples. The only catch? Put *cards.dll* in the same dir as the exe, or somewhere else your environ will find it...

Because of the calls to hdc, I can't find any parallels to WPF.

Comment: You are going to have to start with a WPF tutorial.

Comment: OK, Mods... I apparently wrote it well enough to get an answer that fit the question, and marked it as such. What are your suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7811492/2278086), you can use a [`Bitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) to draw on (you will need to add a reference to `System.Drawing` in your WPF application), and use that `Bitmap` as the source for a WPF [`Image`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control.

MainWindow.xaml

```xml
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="600">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <Image Name="myImage" Stretch="None"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.vb

```vb
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Windows.Interop

Class MainWindow

    Private SQ As Card = New Card(Suit.Spade, Face.Queen)
    Private DK As Card = New Card(Suit.Diamond, Face.King)
    Private C10 As Card = New Card(Suit.Club, Face.Ten)
    Private H2 As Card = New Card(Suit.Heart, Face.Two)
    Private SA As Card = New Card(Suit.Spade, Face.Ace)

    Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded

        Using tempBitmap = New Bitmap(1000, 1000)
            Using g = Graphics.FromImage(tempBitmap)
                SQ.PaintGraphicFace(g, 10, 10)
                DK.PaintGraphicFace(g, 50, 10)
                C10.PaintGraphicFace(g, 110, 200)
                C10.PaintGraphicBack(g, 30, 300)
                H2.PaintGraphicBack(g, 250, 370)
                SA.PaintGraphicFace(g, 200, 50)
                Dim hbmp = tempBitmap.GetHbitmap()
                Dim options = BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions()
                Me.myImage.Source = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(hbmp,
                    IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, options)
            End Using
        End Using

        Me.myImage.InvalidateMeasure()
        Me.myImage.InvalidateVisual()

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Thanks, @Mark, this was awesome! Now that I've gone through all the work, I am doubting that using a bitmap as the interface/output is a good idea... I am leaning toward WPF and individual images... For one thing, hit detection would be easier, and animation is a LOT easier than doing the redraw thing in WinForm... Still, I will create a Winform version of the above test and put it on my blog for others! Thanks again!