# BitmapCache size

Tags: c#, wpf, rendering

How much can this cache hold?

```
UIElement.CacheMode = new BitmapCache();
```

I don't get any exception, but a blurry (jpg-ish) appearance for given absurd size (`ClipToBounds = false`):

```
protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext context)
{
    context.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Red, 1),
        new Point(-1000000, -1000000),
        new Point(1000000, 1000000));
}
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.bitmapcache.aspx) say

> The cache functions when hardware acceleration is not available. In this case, the bitmap is rendered in software, and the maximum bitmap dimensions are 2048 x 2048

And what if hardware acceleration is available (which I tend to think is a standard option for modern PC, no)?

I don't want jpg. And I am trying to estimate if it is possible to use cache for [wpf graph](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25450979/1997232).

Comment: Your assumption is silly, you are defining an image 2M * 2M pixels which represents 4 Terabytes.

Comment: @Aybe, what assumption?