# Bitmap cache on DrawingVisual has blurry parts

Tags: c#, caching, bitmap, geometry, drawingvisual

Recently I switched to `DrawingVisuals` to increase the performance of our trending graphs (especially zooming and panning).

Here's the code I have:

```
blocksToBeRendered = (baseItem as AvgCurve).GetStreamGeometryBlocks(ActualWidth, ActualHeight, _minPoint.X, _maxPoint.X, FixTimeStep ? _timeStep : 0, IsMainChart);

Pen stroke = new Pen((baseItem as AvgCurve).LineBrush, 1);

foreach (GeometryGroup group in blocksToBeRendered)
{
    if (group.Children.Count != 0)
    {
        if (!cachedBlocks[baseItem].Any(x => x.Children[0] == group.Children[0]))
        {
            cachedBlocks[baseItem].Add(group);

            ImprovedDrawingVisual vis = new ImprovedDrawingVisual();

            BitmapCache cache = new BitmapCache() { SnapsToDevicePixels = true };
            vis.CacheMode = cache;

            using (DrawingContext context = vis.RenderOpen())
            {
                RenderOptions.SetEdgeMode(group, EdgeMode.Aliased);
                if (group.Children.Count > 0)
                {
                    context.DrawGeometry(null, stroke, group.Children[0]);
                }
            }

            _host.VisualCollection.Add(vis);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the `ImprovedDrawingVisual`:

```
public class ImprovedDrawingVisual: DrawingVisual
{
    public ImprovedDrawingVisual()
    {
        VisualEdgeMode = EdgeMode.Aliased;
        VisualBitmapScalingMode = BitmapScalingMode.NearestNeighbor;
    }
}
```

Now, the geometries do have `Transforms`, which might be important.

What happens is that the graphs are drawn nicely without bitmap caching (1 px lines), but when I turn on bitmap caching, parts of the graph go all blurry sometimes.

[image: blurry lines]

Does anyone know how I can fix this? I tried changing the `RenderAtScale` of the `DrawingVisual` or turning off the `EdgeMode` setting, but that doesn't help.

**EDIT:** Left out the brush fill geometry to avoid confusion since it's not relevant here.

Comment: You are using `BitmapCache` (see [my](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25507861/1997232) question), which looks like a bitmap using jpg-compession. Perhaps you can implement own `BitmapCache` (which will not be a jpg)? Btw, to have a really high-performance graph I had to use `GDI+` in wpf.

Comment: Do you have an example of using GDI+, how would I go about that starting from my code example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you decide to try `GDI+` in `wpf`, then drawing will looks like this:

```
using GDI = System.Drawing;

private int _counter; // count redraws

protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext context)
{
    if (Figures != null && RenderSize.Height > 0 && RenderSize.Width > 0)
        using (var bitmap = new GDI.Bitmap((int)RenderSize.Width, (int)RenderSize.Height))
        {
            using (var graphics = GDI.Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                foreach (var figure in Figures)
                    figure.Render(this, graphics);
            // draw image
            var hbitmap = bitmap.GetHbitmap();
            var size = bitmap.Width * bitmap.Height * 4;
            GC.AddMemoryPressure(size);
            var image = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(hbitmap, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
            image.Freeze();
            context.DrawImage(image, new Rect(RenderSize));
            DeleteObject(hbitmap);
            GC.RemoveMemoryPressure(size);
            // trigger garbage collecting
            if (_counter++ > 10)
                GC.Collect(3);
      }
}
```

This basically renders `Graph` in place (no deffered `wpf` rendering, well, only blitting of final `image`). You call `InvalidateVisual()` to redraw graph. Notice `GC` thingies, they are must (especially periodic garbage collection if graph gets redrawn frequently).

In my code `Figures` is a list of non-visuals (simple classes, implementing GDI rendering as well). And you have visual children. It's the problem, which I leave for you to solve. The benefit is very high performance.

Comment: I used to have geometries on top of a canvas which were redrawn every time I panned or zoomed. Is this more like that?

Comment: Nope, because visuals and `wpf` is slow. Do you set visuals in `xaml`? Or, saying otherwise, are graph figures (lines, orts, background, etc) **must** be a visual? If answer is "no", then replace them with non-visuals, which only knows how to render self into parent `Graph`.

Comment: I used to have paths, not visuals. These paths had geometries and were added onto the canvas.

Comment: Zooming/panning is performed during rendering. There are *local* coords, to example, point (100,100) of graph. And there are *mouse* coords. When rendering graph you convert local coords to mouse and then use GDI functions to draw lines or whatever. WPF transformation looks good at first, but you still have problem of calculating backwards (aka mouse coords into what point is that). Visuals solve hit-testing, but they are *slow*.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a go at it with a few tests. It kind of sucks that I would have to throw away/heavily adapt all my geometry creation logic though :p

Comment: Okay. I'm implementing GDI right now. It's pretty awesome when you compare the performance to wpf drawing. Really amazing. Thanks.