# How to paint a WPF-Shape mathematically?

Tags: c#, wpf, paint, shapes

I want to paint an WPF-Element like a colorwheel, you know from the HSV color space.
i dont know how to do this, i havnt found a possibility based on the standard brushes (SolidColorBrush, GradientBrush, etc)

How is a (mathematical) painting possible on wpf-shapes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you talk about Brushes and Pens you are talking about GDI+ and in GDI+ you have full control on anything since you are basically deciding which pixel to turn on, not so low of course but using lines, polygons and paths.

for a comparison between GDI+ and WPF or simply for some info regarding how to move from the first to the second, check this one: [C# Transition between GDI+ and WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271686/c-transition-between-gdi-and-wpf) there are some answers with lots of details

Comment: thanks for this link. you inspired me to paint my shape in an BitmapImage and set this as background of an ellipse-shape using the imagebrush. i guess, this should solve my problem