# Design Considerations For a Paint-Like Windows Application

Tags: c#

I'm in process of developing a new front end for an old open source fluid modeling engine written in C.  I am using C# and WPF. The apps network generation requires the user to draw a network of pipes, reservoirs, nodes, tanks, etc.  The app is more or less a fancy version of paint ;)

Right now I have the graphics set up as follows.  I have an embedded win-forms Panel that has mouseclick, mousemove, and paint events.  Mouse click saves the clicked coordinates to an array in the singleton class and then triggers the paint event via `invalidate();`.  The paint event then loops through the array and draws all the node coordinates in the array via: `g.FillEllipse(x,y,20,20);`  The user can click a node and bring up a menu via a function I wrote called `DoesPointExist(xCord, yCord);`.  It loops through the coordinates array and returns true if both xcord and ycord are within 5px of the clicked coordinates.  A somewhat archaic solution but it seems to work well enough.

This has worked pretty well for me thus far.  But in the future I am going to have to give each node (or circle on the Panel) more and more properties.  Nothing fancy, just numerical values like elevation that must be associated with each node.  Also, I'm going to need to add in an option to delete nodes at some point.

I could probably do this by setting all values of the deleted row to 0 and placing in if statement in the paintevents loop to not draw deleted points, or even figure out how to just get rid of the row period and shift all the others down.

My question is there a more intelligent and OOP type way to go about this?  Looping through and array seems a little old fashioned, there must be a better way to make use of C# features.  Is there some sort of object or class I could setup to make this process simpler?  The array is fine but by the end its going to be 40-50 columns.  My background is more based in functional type programming with lower level languages like C.  My program seems very bare of objects and classes other than a singleton glass for global data.

I know there are different ways to skin the cat; but it's important that the code I write will be accessible and easy to modify for future engineers so I'd like to add as much within the OOP paradigm as possible.  My current code is very functional... but not very tidy.

Paint event code:

```
private void wfSurface_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g;
        Graphics h;
        g = wfSurface.CreateGraphics();
        h = wfSurface.CreateGraphics();
        epanet epa = epanet.GetInstance();
        SolidBrush black = new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Black);
        SolidBrush blue = new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Pink);
        SolidBrush green = new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Green);
        System.Drawing.Pen line = new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0));

        //Loop to draw vertical grid lines
        for (int f = 50; f < 1100; f += 50)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(line, f, 0, f, 750);
        }

        //Loop to draw vertical grid lines
        for (int d = 50; d < 750; d += 50)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(line, 0, d, 1100, d);
        }

        //Loop nodes, tanks, and resevoirs
        for (int L = 1; L < index; L += 1)
        {
            g.FillEllipse(black, Convert.ToInt32(epa.newNodeArray[L, 0] - 8), Convert.ToInt32(epa.newNodeArray[L, 1] - 8), 19, 19);
            h.FillEllipse(blue, Convert.ToInt32(epa.newNodeArray[L, 0] - 6), Convert.ToInt32(epa.newNodeArray[L, 1] - 6), 15, 15);
        }

        for (int b = 1; b < resIndex; b += 1)
        {
            g.FillRectangle(green, Convert.ToInt32(epa.ResArray[b, 0] - 8), Convert.ToInt32(epa.ResArray[b, 1] - 8), 16, 16);
        }
        for (int c = 1; c < tankIndex; c += 1)
        {
            g.FillRectangle(black, Convert.ToInt32(epa.tankArray[c, 0] - 8), Convert.ToInt32(epa.tankArray[c, 1] - 8), 20, 20);
            g.FillRectangle(green, Convert.ToInt32(epa.tankArray[c, 0] - 6), Convert.ToInt32(epa.tankArray[c, 1] - 6), 16, 16);
        }
}
```

Code for click event:

```
private void wfSurface_MouseClick(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //Initialize epanet and save clicked coordinates to singleton class
        epanet epa = epanet.GetInstance();
        epa.xCord = e.X;
        epa.yCord = e.Y;

        //Check if point exists, if does open property window, doesn't do whatever drawing control is selected
        if (epa.DoesPointExist(e.X, e.Y, index) == false)
        {
            switch (epa.controlSelected)
            {
                case "Node":
                    epa.newSetCords(index, e.X, e.Y);
                    wfSurface.Invalidate();
                    index += 1;

                    break;

                case "Res":
                    epa.setResCords(resIndex, e.X, e.Y);
                    wfSurface.Invalidate();
                    resIndex += 1;
                    wfPanel.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
                    break;

                case "Tank":
                    epa.setTankCords(tankIndex, e.X, e.Y);
                    wfSurface.Invalidate();
                    tankIndex += 1;
                    break;

                case "Pointer":
                    break;

                default:
                    //epa.newSetCords(index, e.X, e.Y);
                    wfSurface.Invalidate();
                    break;
            }


        }
        else if (epa.DoesPointExist(e.X, e.Y, index) == true)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Point Already Exists");
            if (epa.propOpen == false)
            {
                // Open control properties in right pannel
            }

        }
```

Code for singleton class:

```
public class epanet
```

{
    private static epanet instance = new epanet();

```
private epanet() { }

public static epanet GetInstance()
{
    return instance;
}

//Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog save = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();

//Network Node Data
public int nodeIndex { get; set; }
public int newNodeIndex { get; set; }
public double xCord { get; set; }
public double yCord { get; set; }
public double x1Cord { get; set; }
public double y1Cord { get; set; }
public int selectedPoint { get; set; }
//public List<double> nodeList = new List<double>();

//Saving Data
public int fileCopyNum { get; set; }
public string filename { get; set; }
public string path { get; set; }
public string fullFileName { get; set; }

//Window Condition Data
public bool drawSurfStatus { get; set; }
public bool windowOpen { get; set; }
public bool OpenClicked { get; set; }
public bool saveASed { get; set; }
public bool newClicked { get; set; }
public bool propOpen { get; set; }

//Drawing Controls
public string controlSelected { get; set; }

//Declare Array to store coordinates
public double[,] nodeArray = new double[100000, 3];
public double[,] newNodeArray = new double[100000, 7];
public double[,] ResArray = new double[100000, 7];
public double[,] tankArray = new double[100000, 7];

public void newSetCords(int newNodeIndex, double xCord, double yCord)
{
    newNodeArray[newNodeIndex, 0] = xCord;
    newNodeArray[newNodeIndex, 1] = yCord;
    newNodeArray[nodeIndex, 2] = nodeIndex;

}

public void setResCords(int newNodeIndex, double xCord, double yCord)
{
    ResArray[newNodeIndex, 0] = xCord;
    ResArray[newNodeIndex, 1] = yCord;
    ResArray[nodeIndex, 2] = nodeIndex;

}

public void setTankCords(int newNodeIndex, double xCord, double yCord)
{
    tankArray[newNodeIndex, 0] = xCord;
    tankArray[newNodeIndex, 1] = yCord;
    tankArray[nodeIndex, 2] = nodeIndex;

}

public void setCords(int nodeIndex, double xCord, double yCord)
{
    nodeArray[nodeIndex, 0] = xCord;
    nodeArray[nodeIndex, 1] = yCord;
    //nodeArray[nodeIndex, 2] = nodeIndex;

}

public bool DoesPointExist(double xcord, double ycord, int index)
{
    int count = 1;
    bool outcome = false;        
    while (count < index)
    {            
        if (Math.Abs(xcord - newNodeArray[count, 0]) < 20)
        {
            if (Math.Abs(ycord - newNodeArray[count, 1]) < 20 )
            {                    
                outcome = true;
                selectedPoint = count;
                index = 0;                    
            }
        }
        count += 1;
    }

    return outcome;        
}
```

As I said everything works completely fine.  I'm just looking for some feedback on if there's a more professional way to go about doing this.

Comment: Please show more code.

Comment: MVVM is the only hope... for all of us

Comment: @KirkWoll Got it editing now.

Comment: @HighCore ... until theres jquery for .net

Comment: @Jobo not really. MVVM is about keeping UI and logic separated, while jQuery lets you do the exact opposite. I must admit Im not really familiar with it, though

Comment: @HighCore sorry, forgot the [irony] tags. Your comment sounded like the typical "jquery solves everything" comment :)

Comment: @HighCore Is that really completely possible though?  For example I can't seem to figure out how to get around drawing certain menus at runtime in C# when I'd much rather do them in XAML.

Comment: `"drawing certain menus at runtime"`? - a `Menu` is just a graphical representation of a `List<ICommand>`. I don't see how is that difficult to implement.

Comment: For example I have to draw a grid of textBlocks and textBoxs upon a node being clicked and display all the current values and allow the user to change them if he/she wants to.  For 30 items it comes out to alot of lines of c# code... that or I just don't know what the hell I'm doing ;)

Comment: @steelnation post a question with some code sample and I can help you do it properly in XAML with an `ItemsControl` and a proper `ViewModel`.

Comment: @HighCore Thanks man I really appreciate the help, gonna take lunch and then get that posted.

Comment: Ok posted if you still have time to take a look.  Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you've done much programming in C, you should be familiar with the concept of a linked-list.  It's much more useful than an array, because it lets you delete from any point in the list in constant time.  In C#, you'll want to look into `System.Collections.Generic.List` to make use of it.

Beyond that, standard object-oriented design is to look through your functional requirements and look for nouns, and those should become your classes.  The biggest noun I see in your question is "node."  So instead of having an array of vertices, have a linked list of nodes.  Each node can have properties such as Coordinates and Elevation, and is then extensible if you need more.  Note, if you find your Node class getting cumbersome, that's a huge sign that you should split off other classes.  Any logical grouping should pretty coherently present itself.

Look through your epanet class that you included.  You have functionality to handle files (filename, is it save-as'd, etc).  That should be turned in to a class (in a separate file) just to help keep the files maintainable.  The sequence of arrays you have, all of the same primary dimension define your general node structure.  Put those and your function that operate on those into your Node class.  You already have logic that works; it's just not intuitive to the next reader.  Spend a bit of time questioning your placement of all your code, and asking yourself if there are any logical groupings you can put together.

Your general flow is fine if you want to limit yourself to Winforms/GDI+, and you can obviously get along that way, but since you're programming in WPF, you may want to step up to actually using it while your project is still young.  [C# Transition between GDI+ and WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271686/c-sharp-transition-between-gdi-and-wpf) gives a little bit of a heads-up as how to do so, particularly suggestion 5 of the accepted answer.  There are tons of other references on the web as well.  A quick Google search brought up [Manual rendering of a WPF User Control](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/94ddd25e-7093-4986-b8c8-b647924251f6/) and of course [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025.aspx).  I'll leave WPF advice up to others who know it better than I.

If you don't know yet if you want to use GDI or WPF, you definitely need to have a GDIRenderer class.  Ideally, you should have an IRenderer interface and a GDIRenderer class that implements that interface, though I do find that practically, it's more convenient to make the interface when you have a second object that implements it.  In any case, your Renderer class(es) should take a List of Node as input.  (You currently have them global, but it's generally good to only let one part of code have access to what it needs to, i.e. avoid globals.)  In your current code, GDIRenderer would simply contain and register your OnPaint function.  But by doing this, you isolate all of your rendering into a single class (which should be in a file of its own).  Then, should you decide to move on to WPF, you can substitue the GDIRenderer for a WPFRenderer, which could contain all the code needed to handle the OnRender functionality.  You want to do all you can to separate your business logic from the way you render.

Comment: Got it, thanks brother!  I forgot to that the mousemove event was for highlighting points when mouse goes over them.  You'd think mousehover would be better for that... for some reason I couldn't get it to fire on the canvas whatsoever though.

Comment: @Scott I agree 100% with your first and second paragraphs, but the third one sounds too winforms to me. In WPF there's no such thing as the paint event (whatever that is). There are `DataTemplates`, `ControlTemplates`, `Styles` and whatnot to customize the look and behavior of UI elements.

Comment: @HighCore Thanks man I'll have to look into those.  I think there is some sort of render.someMethod in WPF that is like paint in Winforms. I did say in the post that I embedded a winform Panel in the WPF app though.

Comment: Wow.  I totally missed the bit about this being WPF, and just focused on the (embedded) winform Panel.  Updating my answer...

Comment: Man... I keep changing my mind about which to use.  I mainly ended up going with an embedded WinForm just because there were more tutorials on how to use paint events than renders (at this point I had literally no idea what I was doing).  Don't know if its worth switching back just for consistencies sake at this point...

Comment: Added advice for being indecisive about which way you want to draw to the answer.