# How to move from WinForms to WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, user-interface

I used WPF very little before and some stuff seemed very different to achieve. Coming from a winforms background, what things will seem different and take you a while to figure out.

Off top of my head, I remember not being able to specify which nodes are selected in a treeview control the way it's done in winforms, if I am not wrong.

Comment: If you populate TreeView manually (as you would in WinForms), then you can walk the TreeViewItem nodes and assign to the IsSelected property to select one of them programatically.

Comment: The very first item in the SO FAQ says questions should be "detailed and specific". This is neither IMHO.

Comment: OK, as Jobi Joy points out, this is a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129772/how-to-begin-wpf-development

Answer (score 2):

I remember the whole MVVM principle..

But its okay now.. we are bffs now! :)

Answer (score 2):

Oh, where to begin? WPF and WinForms seem *very* different to me. The concept of defining layouts using markup is quite different, although similar to web development. The fact that you need to make an explicit choice of a layout container (for multiple elements) is novel. I remember trying to add a bunch of elements directly within a Window and getting very confused...

I think to take advantage of all that WPF has to offer, you need to have a WPF mindset. For example, you don't have to use styles, templates, and bindings, but those concepts are where the power of WPF lies.

Comment: WPF seems like a step backwards after using a visual form designer.

Comment: @R. Bembrose: I sort of agree, sort of don't. As with all things WPF, it's...different. I find that working in markup (with a preview) encourages me to make layouts that "flow" naturally, rather than basing everything on fixed positions. The end result is a better interface. Of course, Blend...

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel stated WPF is different and it needs a different Mindset. You have to forget all the UI side assumptions you made/learned while doing Winforms or other conventional UI side development
I have comeacross so many similar kind of questions in this site. Some interesting once are listed bellow. You can find many here.

- [What are the most common mistakes
  made in WPF development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322612/what-are-the-most-common-mistakes-made-in-wpf-development/322620#322620)
- [How to begin WPF development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129772/how-to-begin-wpf-development/129867#129867)
- [When is Winforms the correct choice vs. WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388711/when-is-winforms-the-correct-choice-vs-wpf)

Answer (score 0):

For your selected node in a treeview the ModelView ViewModel approach works well. People have worked out good design patterns now for this kind of thing making the process much more easy.