# Sample application using C# + XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to learn `C#` with `XAML` but some how i am not able to create a sample app.

I am following few tutorials on internet,
but as given in the tutorial i need to select `Blank App (XAML)` template with `Visual C#`.

But in my Visual Studio 2013 Express Edition i don't get option for:
`Installed`->`Templates`->`Visual C#`->`Windows Store`->`Blank App (XAML)`

I have only:
`Installed`->`Templates`->`Visual C#`->`Windows`

And no `Blank App (XAML)` option.

Do i need to install anything else to get this option?
Also What are Windows Store applications?

**UPDATE:**
- My Visual Studio 2013 Express is installed on Windows 7 Machine.
- I am trying to create just a sample application using C# and XAML not specific for Windows Store app.

Comment: Are you using windows 8 (.net 4.5)? Windows 8 has an app store.. called Windows Store

Comment: I have updated the question with more details.

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129772/how-to-begin-wpf-development
<br> It might help you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be that you are not using Windows 8/8.1 which is required for App development. You can however create XAML/WPF windows desktop programs but then you would have to find tutorials specific for WPF.

Comment: So i need windows 8 machine for this? and what version of Visual Studio? Please see my updated question.

Comment: Can you find Visual C# > Windows Desktop > WPF Application. This would give you the project type for creating a desktop application using Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) that also uses XAML.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have installed Visual Studio Express **for Windows Desktop**, instead of **for Windows**.

You can download it here: http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-express-windows-8

Comment: So i need windows 8 machine for this? and what version of Visual Studio? Please see my updated question.

Comment: Yes, you are trying to make a Windows Store app. Windows 7 had no Store, and can't run Windows store apps (so-called "metro" apps)