# Good resources for learning WPF

Tags: wpf

I am very new to WPF and I am interested in learning it. I have gone through some tutorials, but I am looking for a website or book containing projects/assignments along with solutions so that you can code and learn. As I work through a project, I'd like to be able to refer to a solution in case I get stuck somewhere.

Can someone please share any links/material if you have which can give me some WPF  Projects/assignments to work on along with solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I would search StackOverflow ... as there is already a lot of good stuff on this topic.

**In particular, check out: [WPF Sample Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244786/wpf-sample-applications)**

But here are some additional links to get you started in WPF:

- [What are the best resources for learning WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183315/what-are-the-best-resources-for-learning-wpf-net)
- [What did you find hardest to understand when learning WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445114/what-did-you-find-hardest-to-understand-when-learning-wpf)
- [How to begin WPF development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129772/how-to-begin-wpf-development)
- [What WPF books would you recommend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591/what-wpf-books-would-you-recommend)
- [What applications could I study to understand DataModel-View-ViewModel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275098/what-applications-could-i-study-to-understand-datamodel-view-viewmodel)

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I found http://www.drwpf.com/blog/ very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think nobody has referred to the [WPF Boot camp](http://archive.visitmix.com/University/wpf/bc08/Default.aspx), it's 3 days free training by the experts and it was really helpful.

If you want to directly download all videos try [this](http://archive.visitmix.com/University/wpf/bc08/links.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at MVVM pattern: [NDC2009 MVVM talk](http://jonas.follesoe.no/RecordingOfMyMVVMTalkAtNDC2009IsNowOnline.aspx) is really good.

Answer (score 0):

I've read a few WPF books. This one has been my favorite:

[Pro WPF in C# 2008](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590599551)

I would also recommend this one:

[WPF in Action with Visual Studio 2008](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988223)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for some hands-on labs.  Check these out:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=05755a9d-98fa-4f16-bfdc-023e3fd34763&displaylang=en