# How can I make my bound WPF DataGrid sortable?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework-4, binding, wpfdatagrid

My WPF4 DataGrid is bound to a non-sortable collection - ObjectResult(of t) . I can't figure out how to instead use a sortable collection such as ListCollectionView.

**Details:** When the application loads the user initiates a search to fill the DataGrid and other editable controls. To perform the search I'm building an ObjectQuery(of t) based on the users filter choices. The Execute method of the ObjectQuery returns and ObjectResult which I set as my CollectionViewSource.Source. In the XAML the DataGrid is bound to the CollectionViewSource which is the DataContext for the screen I've created.

```
System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<LabSample> labSamplesQuery = this.GetLabSamplesFiltered_Query(_labEntitiesContext, sampleID_LIKE, xxx_LIKE, yyy_LIKE); 
System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult<LabSample> labSamples =  labSamplesQuery.Execute(System.Data.Objects.MergeOption.AppendOnly);
_labSamplesCollectionViewSource.Source = labSamples;
```

Because the DataGrid is bound to ObjectResult(of t) it's not sortable. **How can I get my query results (labSamples) into a sortable & updatable collection** before asssigning it as the source of my data (CollectionViewSource.Source)?

Comment: Do you need the collection to be updateable?

Comment: Yes. This seems like such a basic requirement - users search for data and I dump results in a grid so users can edit the records. Where is there a web page or video to learn how to do this? I marked Aaron's answer as accepted a little too soon. His answer gives me a sortable grid with the ICollectionView as the DataGrid.ItemsSource, but my other controls are no longer bound. I want my form's DataContext to match whatever I use for the DataGrid's ItemSource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your collection with an `ICollectionView` and return that to your bound `DataGrid`.

```
    private ICollectionView _view;

    public ICollectionView Samples
    {
        get 
        {
            if (_view == null)
            {
                _view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(new ObservableCollection<LabSample>(labSamples));
                _view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("PropertyName", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
            }

            return _view;
        }
    }
```

You can also set the sorting logic within XAML. Bea has an article on achieving that [here](http://www.beacosta.com/blog/?p=17). If you make the `ObservableCollection<LabSamples>` a class level variable or contained within a service holding onto the wrapped reference your changes will then be reflected in the `DataGrid`.

Comment: This is the answer I've been scouring the web for. Thanks! Can I assign the ICollectionView as my _labSamplesCollectionViewSource.Source and use it as the DataContext for all editable controls?

Comment: In the above example the Samples property would be a property on an object which would be the ViewModel or DataContext for a given View. Within your XAML you can bind directly to Samples as the underlying collection was already wrapped when we made a call to GetDefaultView; give this a try as it should suffice. If you want to stick with using an explicit CollectionViewSource you would need to assign your _labSamplesCollectionViewSource.Source to the newly defined ObservableCollection<LabSamples> where your CollectionViewSource.View would then contain the reference to the ICollectionView.

Comment: In addition ICollectionView implements IEnumerable, so whatever other controls you referenced that are no longer bound should be able to bind as they did before. Can you update your question to include information about the other controls? If you just want a collection with notification changes, wrap your results...new ObservableCollection<LabSample>(labSamples)

Comment: I said this is the answer a little too quickly. The answer you gave works nicely when I set the DataGrid.ItemsSource to the created _view. But I don't know what to use now as the DataContext for my editable controls (my question just above). If anyone knows good resources for creating a basic WPF & EF data entry form that is initially poplulated by a users filter please let me know. The filter/search could grow to be complex so I'm hoping to use a composable LINQ ObjectQuery(of t).

Comment: @DeveloperDan What were you using before as the DataContext?

Comment: My original DataContext was the one created in XAML by dragging a table from the data sources window (a CollectionViewSource). I haven't graduated to the world of ViewModels yet. Is it important for me to code this as a property? I tried to add your code in-line following my labSamplesQuery.Execute. I left off your SortDescriptors line and tried just adding your GetDefaultView line. The returned object is ListCollectionView and not ICollectionView. Because of this I get an error when I assign the ListCollectionView (_view) to my _labSamplesCollectionViewSource.Source. So, I'm still struggling.

Comment: @DeveloperDan ListCollectionview inherits CollectionView which implements ICollectionView. Ideally using a ViewModel approach will make your life easier down the road. However if you set your _labSamplesCollectionViewSource.Source to the  ObservableCollection<LabSample>(labSamples) then the _labSamplesCollectionViewSource.View would be the associated View for the backing collection. That should allow you to use the predefined resource in XAML if that is your goal.

Comment: Finally, it works! And I only had to modify one line in my original code. The last line I changed to _labSamplesCollectionViewSource.Source = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<LabSample>(labSamples);

Comment: That's what you've been telling me to do all along but I didn't grasp the concept of "wrap the results in...". Thanks for your persistence in helping me. I believe other developers like me who've done Windows Forms with ADO.Net need a better resource to learn WPF CRUD. What I've found is sub-standard. Aaron I'm curious how you learn this stuff? Thanks again!

Comment: @DeveloperDan Sure thing, glad I could help. The best way to learn is to immerse yourself within it. That is how I have picked it up over time...there is an SO post as well talking about additional resources...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526150/good-resources-for-learning-wpf

Answer (score 1):

WPF DataGrid will not be sortable becouse of deferred loading. You need to use ToList() method as follows:
.....
_labSamplesCollectionViewSource.Source = labSamples.ToList(); Now datagrid should be sortable.