# WPF Ribbon controls book

Tags: wpf

Is there any book or links that I can read some tutorial about the WPF ribbon control. I need to get some basics . Also can any one recommend  good book in WPF or a starter kit.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For learning the WPF Ribbon**

- [CodePlex project with the WPF Ribbon Preview from MS](http://wpf.codeplex.com/)
- [Ribbon Feature Walkthrough](http://windowsclient.net/wpf/wpf35/wpf-35sp1-ribbon-walkthrough.aspx) on WindowsClient.net
- [HOW TO: Use and add ribbon to your WPF applications?](http://www.uxpassion.com/2008/11/how-to-use-add-ribbon-to-wpf-applications/) on UxPassion.com

**WPF Book Recommendations**

Take a look at the [What WPF books would you recommend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591/what-wpf-books-would-you-recommend) thread. Though, the thread is over a year old, the books there are still highly recommended.

**Learning WPF**

Finally, take a look at this post on learning WPF: [MVVM: Tutorial from start to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405739/mvvm-tutorial-from-start-to-finish/2034333#2034333)

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.uxpassion.com/2008/11/how-to-use-add-ribbon-to-wpf-applications/) looks fairly comprehensive. It uses Expression Blend 2 to create the ribbon, but if you have 3 then I would have thought it would translate fairly readily.

But a search for "wpf ribbon control tutorial" should turn up quite a few. Vary your search terms if non are exactly what you're looking for.