# books to recommend to study WPF

Tags: wpf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What WPF books would you recommend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591/what-wpf-books-would-you-recommend)

Is there any good book to recommend for learning WPF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend WPF in Action with Visual Studio 2008 for an introduction (it covers .NET 3.5 SP1), but for me the best WPF book out there is Matthew MacDonald's 'Pro WPF in C# 2010: Windows Presentation Foundation in .NET 4' (http://apress.com/book/view/9781430272052), which is more advanced.

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend [Sams Teach Yourself WPF in 24 Hours](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672329859).

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend Matthew A. Stoecker's MCTS Self-Paced Training Kit (Exam 70-502): Microsoft® .NET Framework 3.5—Windows® Presentation Foundation (search for 70-502 on O Reilly) and the WPF courses from Pluralsight. The labs in the 1st reference are well-designed and I had no problems that it is based on .NET FW 3.5.